# I have a date in "2017-05-26T04:08:00.000+05:30" in XMLGregorianCalendar i need to convert it to 2017-05-26T04:08:00.000z

Tags: java, xml, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a date in "2017-05-26T04:08:00.000+05:30" in XMLGregorianCalendar i need to convert it to 2017-05-26T04:08:00.000Z in XMLGregorianCalendar itself.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: which version of java you are using?

Comment: Well those two dates *mean* different things.  So please explain what you mean by "convert".

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can set the fields of an `XMLGregorianCalendar` individually. So just do

```
    yourXmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone(0);
    System.out.println(yourXmlGregorianCalendar);
```

This prints:

```
2017-05-26T04:08:00.000Z
```

I hope you are aware that the new time does not equal the old time. Rather it equals 2017-05-26T09:38 at your original time zone offset of +05:30.

Edit: How to get an XMLGregorianCalendar date without timezone "2017-05-26T04:08:00"? That is, I don’t want any milliseconds either!

Let me see, didn’t I see something in this in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#setTimezone-int-)? It says: “Unset this field by invoking the setter with a parameter value of [`DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants.html#FIELD_UNDEFINED),” In fact it says that for all the setters that take an `int` argument. Let’s try that:

```
    yourXmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    yourXmlGregorianCalendar.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    System.out.println(yourXmlGregorianCalendar);
```

This prints:

```
2017-05-26T04:08:00
```

Aren’t we there?

Comment: and how to get an XMLGregorianCalendar  date without timezone "2017-05-26T04:08:00" ?

Comment: That gives me this result "2017-05-26T04:08:00.000" i want "2017-05-26T04:08:00"

Comment: Edited again. @PeterOsta

Comment: If reading the documentation makes one a genius. :-) Glad it worked! :-)